# Making decisions based on kind of input

Tags: java, oop

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataStructure s = new DataStructure();
        Input in = new Input();
        Data x = null;
        while ((x = in.readNext()) != null) {
            if (x instanceof InsertData) {
                s.insert((InsertData)x);
            } else if (x instanceof QueryData) {
                System.out.println(s.query((QueryData)x));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Input` reads user input and returns it in the form of `Data` using method `Data readNext()`.

`Data` can be `InsertData` or `QueryData` (they also have different fields, i.e. form of data to insert is different than query).

What I'd like to do is read `Data` and perform insert/query on `DataStructure s`, depending on what type of `Data` was returned by `readNext()`.

Code above is my simple solution for this problem, but it uses conversion and instanceof which isn't a great coding style. Can you suggest any better solution?

Another solution I thought of would be to have a method `void performAction(DataStructure s)` in `Data` which would be overriden by `InsertData`/`QueryData` and perfom corresponding action on `DataStructure`, but I think it would unnecessarily bind `DataStructure` with `Data`, which wouldn't be a good style either. Meaning, I'd like to keep input and performing actions apart, because reading data and doing something with it are kinda different things.

Answer (score 0):

Add method `performAction(Data)` to class `DataStructure`.
Then add abstract method `performOperation()` to class `Data`.
Override method `performOperation()` in class `InsertData` and class `QueryData`.
Method `performAction(Data)` in class `DataStructure` would be as follows:

```java
public void performAction(Data x) {
    x.performOperation();
}
```

and your `while` loop (in your method `main()`) would be:

```java
while ((x = in.readNext()) != null) {
   s.performAction(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a generic `process(Data data)` method in the `DataStructure` class, that inserts or queries the data depending on the instance type. This way, the `DataStructure` class is responsible for the decision making, instead of the`Data` class.

If you're using Java 14, you could get rid of the explicit cast as well (see https://www.baeldung.com/java-pattern-matching-instanceof).